# No static method checkHandlerThread(Landroid/os/Handler;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/Preconditions

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I'm facing a crash after setting `minifyEnabled true` in my app/build.gradle.

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0') {
    exclude group:'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

These are the Firebase libraries i use. This crash only arises if set `minifyEnabled true`.

I've tried enabling Multidex too, still unable to resolve the issue.

Crash log:

```
Process: proto.inventa.cct.com.inventaapp, PID: 30410
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method checkHandlerThread(Landroid/os/Handler;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/Preconditions; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions' appears in /data/app/proto.inventa.cct.com.inventaapp-hunIIikgxzy10RXjTw7TYA==/base.apk!classes4.dex)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GmsClientEventManager.onConnectionSuccess(Unknown Source:20)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaw.zab(Unknown Source:292)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaak.zaaq(Unknown Source:125)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaak.onConnected(Unknown Source:105)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabe.onConnected(Unknown Source:101)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaq.onConnected(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaf.onConnected(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$PostInitCallback.handleServiceSuccess(Unknown Source:130)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.deliverCallback(Unknown Source:60)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.deliverCallback(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$CallbackProxy.deliverCallback(Unknown Source:51)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source:270)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to keep these classes (there may be more):

```
-verbose
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** {com.google.android.gms.internal.** initialize(android.content.Context);}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.iid.** {com.google.android.gms.iid.** get(java.lang.String);}
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.** { *; }
```

Comment: Okay. So in case if i get another crash like this, i should add those classes to my proguard rules right?

Comment: I added the above mentioned rules. It's still giving me the same crash.

Comment: With the `-verbose` switch it should tell you what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a dependency conflict.
`play-services-location:17.0.0` depends on `play-services-basement:17.0.0` and `play-services-base:17.0.0`
But
`firebase-messaging:18.0.0` depends on `play-services-basement:16.0.1`

It may be that you have `play-services-base:17.0.0` but `play-services-basement:16.0.1`, which won't work if `play-services-base:17.0.0` is trying to use APIs introduced in `play-services-basement:17.0.0`.

Try updating your `firebase-messaging` dep to at least version `19.0.0`, which does depend on `play-services-basement:17.0.0`.
Similarly, try updating `firebase-analytics` to at least version `17.0.0`

Also consider checking out the strict version matcher plugin, which will give you an error message if a conflict is detected instead of Gradle's default strategy which just chooses one and if it makes the wrong choice may give odd error messages like this.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning#strict_version_matching.

Also I highly encourage *against* `-keep`ing all of the `com.google.android` packages. That will keep all the code in the SDK, even the parts you don't use, drastically reducing how much benefit shrinking will give.